# Why changing Vaadin version in pom.xml makes project unrunnable on TomEE maven plugin?

Tags: maven, tomcat, jakarta-ee, vaadin, apache-tomee

Was looking at a Vaadin+JavaEE tutorial ( https://youtu.be/xwIzwdLZ9eY ) and ran into issues.
Using Java 11 JDK because the program doesn't work at all while using version 16.0.2

App has 2 main src files:
GreetService.java:

```java
package com.example.test;

import com.vaadin.cdi.annotation.VaadinSessionScoped;

/**
 * Data provider bean scoped for each user session.
 */
@VaadinSessionScoped
public class GreetService {

    public String greet(String name) {
        if (name == null || name.isEmpty()) {
            return "Hello anonymous user";
        } else {
            return "Hello " + name;
        }
    }
}
```

MainView.java:

```java
package com.example.test;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.Key;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.ButtonVariant;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.CssImport;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.notification.Notification;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextField;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.PWA;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;

/**
 * The main view contains a simple label element and a template element.
 */
@Route("")
@PWA(name = "Project Base for Vaadin Flow with CDI", shortName = "Project Base", enableInstallPrompt = false)
@CssImport("./styles/shared-styles.css")
@CssImport(value = "./styles/vaadin-text-field-styles.css", themeFor = "vaadin-text-field")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    @Inject
    private GreetService greetService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Use TextField for standard text input
        TextField textField = new TextField("Your name");
        textField.addThemeName("bordered");

        // Button click listeners can be defined as lambda expressions
        Button button = new Button("Say hello",
                e -> Notification.show(greetService.greet(textField.getValue())));

        // Theme variants give you predefined extra styles for components.
        // Example: Primary button is more prominent look.
        button.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);

        // You can specify keyboard shortcuts for buttons.
        // Example: Pressing enter in this view clicks the Button.
        button.addClickShortcut(Key.ENTER);

        // Use custom CSS classes to apply styling. This is defined in shared-styles.css.
        addClassName("centered-content");

        add(textField, button);
    }

}
```

Here is my initial pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.test.basicapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-starter-project</artifactId>
    <name>My Starter Project</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

        <!-- Dependencies -->
        <vaadin.version>14.6.8</vaadin.version>

        <drivers.dir>${project.basedir}/drivers</drivers.dir>
        <drivers.downloader.phase>pre-integration-test</drivers.downloader.phase>
    </properties>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Webjars are only needed when running in Vaadin 13 compatibility mode -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.webjar</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.insites</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymerelements</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.webcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-cdi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Added to provide logging output as Flow uses -->
        <!-- the unbound SLF4J no-operation (NOP) logger implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>package tomee:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomee.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tomeeClassifier>webprofile</tomeeClassifier>
                    <context>ROOT</context>
                    <synchronization>
                        <extensions>
                            <extension>.class</extension>
                        </extensions>
                    </synchronization>
                    <reloadOnUpdate>true</reloadOnUpdate>
                    <systemVariables>
                        <openejb.system.apps>true</openejb.system.apps>
                        <tomee.serialization.class.blacklist>-</tomee.serialization.class.blacklist>
                    </systemVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--
                Take care of synchronizing java dependencies and imports in
                package.json and main.js files.
                It also creates webpack.config.js if not exists yet.
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
            <id>production</id>
            <properties>
                <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>it</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomee.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>start</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <checkStarted>true</checkStarted>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>stop</id>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>stop</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <simpleLog>true</simpleLog>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <!-- Runs the integration tests (*IT) after the server is started -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.22.2</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                            <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <!-- Pass location of downloaded webdrivers to the tests -->
                                <webdriver.chrome.driver>${webdriver.chrome.driver}</webdriver.chrome.driver>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.lazerycode.selenium</groupId>
                        <artifactId>driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.17</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <onlyGetDriversForHostOperatingSystem>true
                            </onlyGetDriversForHostOperatingSystem>
                            <rootStandaloneServerDirectory>
                                ${project.basedir}/drivers/driver
                            </rootStandaloneServerDirectory>
                            <downloadedZipFileDirectory>
                                ${project.basedir}/drivers/driver_zips
                            </downloadedZipFileDirectory>
                            <customRepositoryMap>
                                ${project.basedir}/drivers.xml
                            </customRepositoryMap>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <!-- use phase "none" to skip download step -->
                                <phase>${drivers.downloader.phase}</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>selenium</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

After maven update doing maven build runs the app fine.
Then, I change Vaadin version in pom.xml from 14.6.8 to 20.0.7, do maven project update and build again, getting some severe errors and visiting localhost:8080 shows a tomcat HTTP status 404 page.

Console output after 2nd try of "maven build":

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/TpS/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.18.0.20210402-1458/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/C:/Users/TpS/eclipse/jee-2021-06/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/6/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/TpS/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.18.0.20210402-1458/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/C:/Users/TpS/eclipse/jee-2021-06/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/6/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
[INFO] ------------< com.example.test.basicapp:my-starter-project >------------
[INFO] Building My Starter Project 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ my-starter-project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\TpS\eclipse-workspace\my-starter-project\src\main\resources
[INFO] --- vaadin-maven-plugin:20.0.7:prepare-frontend (default) @ my-starter-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ my-starter-project ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ my-starter-project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\TpS\eclipse-workspace\my-starter-project\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ my-starter-project ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ my-starter-project ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\TpS\eclipse-workspace\my-starter-project\target\surefire-reports
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [my-starter-project] in [C:\Users\TpS\eclipse-workspace\my-starter-project\target\my-starter-project-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\TpS\eclipse-workspace\my-starter-project\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [807 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\TpS\eclipse-workspace\my-starter-project\target\my-starter-project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] --- tomee-maven-plugin:7.1.1:run (default-cli) @ my-starter-project ---
[INFO] TomEE was unzipped in 'C:\Users\TpS\eclipse-workspace\my-starter-project\target\apache-tomee'
[INFO] Removed not mandatory default webapps
[INFO] Installed 'C:\Users\TpS\eclipse-workspace\my-starter-project\target\my-starter-project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war' in C:\Users\TpS\eclipse-workspace\my-starter-project\target\apache-tomee\webapps\ROOT.war
[INFO] Starting synchronizer with an update interval of 5000
[INFO] TomEE will run in development mode
[INFO] Running 'org.apache.openejb.maven.plugin.run'. Configured TomEE in plugin is localhost:8080 (plugin shutdown port is 8005 and https port is null)
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener (file:/C:/Users/TpS/eclipse-workspace/my-starter-project/target/apache-tomee/lib/tomee-catalina-7.1.1.jar) to field java.lang.reflect.Field.modifiers
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
05-Sep-2021 05:56:08.810 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server version:        Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/8.5.41 (7.1.1)
05-Sep-2021 05:56:08.811 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server built:          May 4 2019 09:17:16 UTC
05-Sep-2021 05:56:08.811 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server number:         8.5.41.0
05-Sep-2021 05:56:08.811 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke OS Name:               Windows 10
...

Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/8.5.41 (7.1.1)
05-Sep-2021 05:56:09.769 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deploying web application archive [C:\Users\TpS\eclipse-workspace\my-starter-project\target\apache-tomee\webapps\ROOT.war]
05-Sep-2021 05:56:09.776 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.init ------------------------- localhost -> /
05-Sep-2021 05:56:09.778 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.util.JarExtractor.extract Extracting jar: C:\Users\TpS\eclipse-workspace\my-starter-project\target\apache-tomee\webapps\ROOT.war
[INFO] Waiting for command: [quit, exit, reload]
05-Sep-2021 05:56:10.361 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.util.JarExtractor.extract Extracted path: C:\Users\TpS\eclipse-workspace\my-starter-project\target\apache-tomee\webapps\ROOT
05-Sep-2021 05:56:10.362 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog.info Using 'openejb.session.manager=org.apache.tomee.catalina.session.QuickSessionManager'
...
org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader.startUp Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [CdiPlugin]
05-Sep-2021 05:56:12.796 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiScanner.handleBda Using annotated mode for file:/C:/Users/TpS/eclipse-workspace/my-starter-project/target/apache-tomee/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/atmosphere-runtime-2.4.30.slf4jvaadin1.jar looking all classes to find CDI beans, maybe think to add a beans.xml if not there or add the jar to exclusions.list
05-Sep-2021 05:56:12.837 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ProjectStageProducer.initProjectStage Computed the following DeltaSpike ProjectStage: Production
05-Sep-2021 05:56:13.208 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.configureInterceptors Interceptor class : org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.throttling.ThrottledInterceptor is already defined
05-Sep-2021 05:56:13.208 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.configureInterceptors Interceptor class : org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.lock.LockedInterceptor is already defined
05-Sep-2021 05:56:13.208 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.configureInterceptors Interceptor class : 
...
05-Sep-2021 05:56:13.425 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.validateInjectionPoints All injection points were validated successfully.
05-Sep-2021 05:56:13.462 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication OpenWebBeans Container has started, it took 969 ms.
05-Sep-2021 05:56:13.467 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Deployed Application(path=C:\Users\TpS\eclipse-workspace\my-starter-project\target\apache-tomee\webapps\ROOT)
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.DevModeInitializer - Starting dev-mode updaters in C:\Users\TpS\eclipse-workspace\my-starter-project folder.
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO dev-updater - Visited 79 classes. Took 20 ms.
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO dev-updater - Added 4 default dependencies to main package.json
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO dev-updater - Running `pnpm install` to resolve and optionally download frontend dependencies. This may take a moment, please stand by...
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.FrontendTools - using 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\npx.cmd --yes --quiet pnpm@5' for frontend package installation
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO dev-updater - Frontend dependencies resolved successfully.
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO dev-updater - Copying frontend resources from jar files ...
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO dev-updater - Visited 28 resources. Took 73 ms.
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO dev-updater - Visited 79 classes. Took 4 ms.
05-Sep-2021 05:57:24.902 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        ...
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ApplicationConfiguration.lambda$get$0(ApplicationConfiguration.java:63)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServletContext.getAttribute(VaadinServletContext.java:73)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ApplicationConfiguration.get(ApplicationConfiguration.java:49)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.VaadinAppShellInitializer.init(VaadinAppShellInitializer.java:110)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.VaadinAppShellInitializer.initialize(VaadinAppShellInitializer.java:79)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.VaadinServletContextStartupInitializer.process(VaadinServletContextStartupInitializer.java:42)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ClassLoaderAwareServletContainerInitializer.lambda$onStartup$2(ClassLoaderAwareServletContainerInitializer.java:81)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ClassLoaderAwareServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(ClassLoaderAwareServletContainerInitializer.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5225)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more
05-Sep-2021 05:57:24.903 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Error deploying web application archive [C:\Users\TpS\eclipse-workspace\my-starter-project\target\apache-tomee\webapps\ROOT.war]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:758)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:744)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:980)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1851)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
05-Sep-2021 05:57:24.904 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deployment of web application archive [C:\Users\TpS\eclipse-workspace\my-starter-project\target\apache-tomee\webapps\ROOT.war] has finished in [75,135] ms
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19] INFO dev-updater - Skipping `pnpm install` because the frontend packages are already installed in the folder 'C:\Users\TpS\eclipse-workspace\my-starter-project\node_modules' and the hash in the file 'C:\Users\TpS\eclipse-workspace\my-starter-project\node_modules\.vaadin\vaadin.json' is the same as in 'package.json'
05-Sep-2021 05:57:24.916 INFO [Catalina-startStop-1] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Unable to set the web application class loader property [clearReferencesRmiTargets] to [true] as the property does not exist.
05-Sep-2021 05:57:24.916 INFO [Catalina-startStop-1] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Unable to set the web application class loader property [clearReferencesObjectStreamClassCaches] to [true] as the property does not exist.
05-Sep-2021 05:57:24.916 INFO [Catalina-startStop-1] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Unable to set the web application class loader property [clearReferencesThreadLocals] to [true] as the property does not exist.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19] INFO dev-updater - Copying frontend resources from jar files ...
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19] INFO dev-updater - Visited 28 resources. Took 53 ms.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19] INFO dev-webpack - Starting webpack-dev-server
05-Sep-2021 05:57:25.060 WARNING [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [135] milliseconds.
05-Sep-2021 05:57:25.063 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
05-Sep-2021 05:57:25.070 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
05-Sep-2021 05:57:25.072 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server startup in 75372 ms
[38;5;35m
------------------ Starting Frontend compilation. ------------------
[0m[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19] INFO dev-webpack - Running webpack to compile frontend resources. This may take a moment, please stand by...
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19] INFO dev-webpack - Started webpack-dev-server. Time: 4617ms
```

So what do I do? I change Vaadin version in pom.xml back to 14.6.8 and the result is.... the app is not working doing a maven build with console outputing probably almost exactly the same as in a previous attempt

My first assumption was that changing dependencies/plugin versions in pom.xml back and forth should be a so to speak reversible action. Could someone explain what is potentially happening here and possible solutions (1. App doesn't work after reverting Vaadin versions with which the app worked previously.  2. Using JDK 16.0.2 the app doesn't work at all even when targeting Java 11 in pom.xml)?

Comment: Have you cleaned the project? Have you tried letting the plugins regenerate the node-related files in the project root?

Comment: I have tried Eclipse-->Project-->Clean... and Maven clean, neither of those helped. Don't know how to let plugins regenerate node-related files in the project root, I'm quite new to all of this.

Comment: Go to start.vaadin.com and generate a project for Vaadin 20. There are a few changes. For example the @PWA annotation must be on a class that implements AppShellConfigurator. Compare your project with the generated one

Answer (score 2):

Deleting node_modules folder, package.json, and pnpm-lock.yaml helped.

(Info from here: https://vaadin.com/docs/v20/guide/upgrading)